how to update class globally in R without breaking CRAN rules
I am writing the function that updates database after computational work is done. I want to update the object class from c("Process") to c("Saved", "Process") for the returned object. What I am looking for is a way to this of the passed object as mutable.
class(x) <- c("Process")

save_function <- function(x){
save(x)
class(x) <- c("Saved", "Process")
x
}

y <- save_function(x) # this will assign to y, but not to x

save_function(x) # this will not reassign to x and the result is lost.

As I am writing to database, it makes sense that it should be overriden no matter if the user reassigned it or not .

You can use environment objects for that. Have a look at ‘R6’ for an example of an implementation.

Or even see section 10.7 of https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf (although you might need to use something like assign("total", total-amount, parent.env(environment())) in place of <<- to prevent complaints from CRAN)

Functions in R tend to avoid side effects, they should return updated values. That's the spirit of functional programming. There are object oriented patterns available in R as well if that's what you really want. See https://adv-r.hadley.nz/oo.html for example.

@BenBolker but this will assign to a new name "total", right?

@Ben That is, frankly, a terrible suggestion. You pay lip service to this in your answer, but why bring it up at all? Using reference types, as suggested in my initial comment, solves the problem in a much cleaner way.

Which suggestion? The one that references "Introduction to R", or the one in my answer? I don't object at all to someone posting an answer that shows how to use R6 to achieve the OP's goal ...

You can do what you want but it's a bit tricky:
x <- NA
class(x) <- c("Process")

save_function <- function(x) {
    orig_name <- deparse(substitute(x))
    class(x) <- c("Saved", "Process")
    ## assign to original symbol in *calling* environment
    assign(orig_name, x, parent.frame())
    return(x)
}

print(class(x))
## [1] "Process"
y <- save_function(x)
print(class(x))
## [1] "Saved"   "Process"

This version both assigns the returned value to y and modifies the value of x in the original environment. If you just want to do the latter, you could return invisible(NULL)) instead (invisible() is just some sugar so that the return value isn't printed).
<opinion>
As commenters point out, this is not really idiomatic in R; mutable state tends to be achieved by storing objects in environments, or using one of the (many!) object orientation systems. But as long as you don't go too far down the rabbit hole, you won't get into too much trouble assigning in a different environment from time to time ...
</opinion>
